# Is the Liskov Principle violated if overridden methods return a different value?

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles

Below is my base class which has ReturnAddress method which returns 'Address one' and in child class Im overriding same method which return 'Address two'.

```
public class Base     
{         
     public virtual string ReturnAddress()        
     {             
         return "Address one";         
     }    
 }    


public class Derived : Base     
{                  
    public override string ReturnAddress()         
     {             
        return "Address Two";         
     }
}

//Object declaration for base and derived

Base base = new Base();

Derived der = new Derived();

var result = der.ReturnAddress(); // will return "Address Two"
but if we replace der object with base object 

var result = base.ReturnAddress(); //Will return "Address One"
```

So child object is not replacable by parent object.

I want to know that is above example breaking [Liskov Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) ?

Comment: Why are you using an overriden method in the first place? It's not like you're reusing code..

Comment: What did you mean with *if we replace der object with base object*?

Comment: I always thought it was "das object".

Comment: People from the [Computer Sciences](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) community may provide you a good answer.

Comment: @l19: Why should overriding necessarily imply reusing any code?

Answer (score 10):

The LSP doesn't state that a child object will always do exactly the same thing as a parent object, when you treat it as the parent object.  There would be no purpose to inheriting from an object if that was the case.

Rather, the point is that you can treat a `Base` object as if it's a `Base` object *or any object derived from it*.  The code should work regardless of whether the actual object instance is of type `Base` or `Derived`.  Now if your code will fail if `Address Two` is returned, and it *expects* `Address One` to be returned, then you'll have broken LSP.  If your code will work regardless of which string is returned, so long *a* string is returned, then you're fulfilling the LSP.

The LSP states that you should be able to replace objects of one type with objects of the other, "without altering any of the desirable properties of that program" (taken from the wikipedia page). Those desirable properties could be, "has a property that returns a string" or it could be "has a property that returns 'Address One'". What you consider "desirable" about that object determines whether or not the LSP is violated.

Comment: In a strict sense LSP covers *"behavior"*. The distinction here is the *value/result* differs, not the *"behavior"*. (I believe the OP is wishing to draw out the line between the two.)

Comment: I'd state LSP as "The derived class must fulfill the *contract* of the base class".

Comment: @user2864740 It states that you should be able to replace objects of one type with objects of the other, "without altering any of the desirable properties of that program" (taken from the wikipedia page).  Those desirable properties could be, "has a property that returns a string" or it could be "has a property that returns 'Address One'".  What you consider "desirable" about that object determines whether or not the LSP applies here.

Comment: "desirable" is covered by the defined behavior, not the type system.

Comment: @Servy: That last comment of yours is so well-phrased that you should add it to your answer IMO.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not.

That is, unless you are changing the *meaning* of address.

For example, if the base was a postal address, but the derived was an IP address,  the Gettysburg Address or a misspelling of 'a dress'.  Whilst these have the same word, and so the compiler won't be clever enough to stop you, they are very different words.

In other words, you aren't playing linguistic tricks on the word *address*.

Answer (score 3):

Reading from [the description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#Principle):

- The types are substitutable (they are both reference types).
- Covariance is not violated in return types (they happen to remain the same).
- Contravariance is not violated in inputs (since there are no inputs).
- No new exceptions are candidates to be thrown (both implementations call the same method).
- No preconditions are strengthened (there are no obvious preconditions in your particular example).
- No postconditions are weakened (as above).
- No invariants are modified (since both classes happen to be stateless).
- The history rule isn't violated (since the derived class doesn't introduce mutable state that could be observable from the base class).

According to the above, you're not violating LSP.

But if the rest of your program has some requirements that we can't infer from these two classes (for example, perhaps only one specific string is acceptable as the return value of these objects), then these classes aren't useful to you, regardless of whether they respect or violate LSP.